# UsernamePasswordCredentials contains a null username or password

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, atlassian-sourcetree, visual-studio-mac

I am using visual studio 2017 for Mac.

[image]

I am having troubling pushing the changes via its subversion.

Even if I set the git username, password via terminal this IDE resets it to null and If I enter the right credentials also its not taking.

But I am able to do this all using source tree without any problem.

Is it a known issue

Comment: I even switched to the beta channel and (although the dialog boxes reporting the errors are now correctly displayed), the problem persists.